# React native Android 12(31), 13(33) text align in lineHeight different

Tags: android, react-native, text, text-align, line-height

React Natvie `<Text>` component has different text align in their lineHeight area when Android os
under 12, 13

This is 13(33)

[image]

This is 12(31)

[image]

Anyone know reason? font? os?

Use "NotoSansKR" Font

Please Answer anyone know

style code

```
  filterName: {
    fontFamily: 'NotoSansKR-Regular',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: '400',
    marginBottom: 2,
    color: Color.gray900,
  },
```